# Finding a File and taking backup in the same directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, copy, backup

Lets say i have a folder `/tmp` and you have some files `abc.sh`, `kbc.sh`, `cdg.sh`, `nope.py`, `kim.r`, `uio.csv`. Now if you are copying new versions of `abc.sh`, `kbc.sh` from a different server like your prod but you want to take your existing file backups in the same folder like `abc.sh-12-08-2016`, `kbc.sh-12-08-2016`, `cdg.sh-12-08-2016`, how can you do this in one command. So here is the answer

```
find * -type f -exec cp {} {}_`date + "%m-%d-%Y"` \;
```

Above command will take back up of all files in that folder.

If you want to only take back up of .sh files

```
find * -type f -name "*.sh" -exec cp {} {}_`date + "%m-%d-%Y"` \;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
find * -type f -exec cp {} {}_date + "%m-%d-%Y" \;
```

Above command will take back up of all files in that folder.

If you want to only take back up of .sh files

```
find * -type f -name "*.sh" -exec cp {} {}_date + "%m-%d-%Y" \;
```